# Struggling with location blocks in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I got a new slice off slicehost, for the purposes of playing around and learning nginx and more about deployment generally.  I installed a ruby app on there (which i'll call app1) which uses passenger.  I made it the default app to use for that server with the following server block in my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my server ip>;
    root <path to app1 public folder>;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

This works fine.  However, i want to try a few different apps out on this slice, and so thought i would set it up like so:

http:///app1

http:///app2

etc.  I thought i would be able to do that by adding a location block, and moving the app1 specific stuff into it like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my server ip>;

    location ^~ /app1 {
        root <path to app1 public folder>;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

However, on doing this (and restarting nginx of course), going to the plain ip address gives the 'welcome to nginx' message (which i'd expect).  But, going to /app1 gives an error message:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /app1 was not found on this server.
```

This is distinct from the error message i get when i go to another path on that ip, eg /foo:

```
404 Not Found
nginx/0.8.53
```

So, it's like nginx knows about that location but i've not set it up properly.  Can anyone set me straight?  Should i set up different server blocks instead of using locations? I'm sure this is simple but can't work it out.

Cheers, max

Comment: As a sidenote, it is discouraged to place [root in a location block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block)

Answer (score 3):

What you're after is name virtual hosting. The idea is that each domain is hosted on the same IP, and nginx chooses the virtualhost to serve based on the `Host:` header in the HTTP request, which is sent by the browser.

To use name virtual hosting, use the domain you want to serve instead of your server's IP for the `server_name` directive.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app1.com;

  location / {
    root /srv/http/app1/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
}
```

Then, to host more apps on the same box, just declare a separate `server { }` block for each one.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app2.com;

  location / {
    root /srv/http/app2/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
}
```

I'm using unicorn instead of passenger, but the vhost part of the structure is the same for any backend.

The global nginx config (which on its own hosts nothing): https://github.com/benhoskings/babushka-deps/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf.erb

The template wrapper for each virtualhost: https://github.com/benhoskings/babushka-deps/blob/master/nginx/vhost.conf.erb

The details of the unicorn virtualhost: https://github.com/benhoskings/babushka-deps/blob/master/nginx/unicorn_vhost.common.erb

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see the real problem here tho,
in order for you to figure that out 
you need to view the nginx log files on most systems at:
/var/log/nginx/
and open the relevant access file here(might be error.log)
in there you can see what url nginx exactly tried to access and why did it fail.
What I really think is happening, that you got the root path wrong,
maybe it should be alias instead because
if you are proxifying the connection to another app, it might get the
"app1" word in the url instead of a direct one.

so please try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my server ip>;

    location /app1 {
        alias <path to app1 public folder>;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

and see weather it works and also try to view the logs first to really determine whats the problem.

Comment: log path on a mac using brew is `/usr/local/var/log/nginx`

Answer (score 2):

I think its just a slight syntax problem:

```
 location ~ ^/app1 { ...
```

should work, or a little more efficient:

```
 location = /app1 { ...
```

Comment: Thanks martin.  I tried both of those but still get the same `The requested URL /app1 was not found on this server. ` error.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that your Rails app probably wasn't designed to run from a subdirectory.  Passenger has a directive that will fix this:

```
passenger_base_uri /app1;
```

However, running Rails apps in subdirectories is somewhat non-standard.  If you can, a better option may be to set up subdomains using nginx's virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to host more apps on the same server with base uri. Try this:

```
root /srv/http/;
passenger_base_uri /app_1;
passenger_base_uri /app_2
```

Also under /srv/http, create 2 symlinks:

```
ln -s /srv/http/app_1 /srv/http/app1/public
ln -s /srv/http/app_2 /srv/http/app2/public
```

The app1 can be accessed under: http://domain.com/app_1.

Here is more for reading: `http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri`